# How to model an financial accounting system in Django?

Tags: python, django

The Django application I'm developing for a taxi company has following modules,

1. Trips
2. Customers (who buy products)
3. Vehicles
4. Drivers

Each trip is constituted by selecting a customer, a vehicle and a driver along with a few other parameters.

I will be recording every single trip, and the revenue generated because of it.

I also would like to assign this revenue generated to the individual customer who took the vehicle, and to the vehicle which was used in the trip. Since I would like to have a deeper understanding of the customer's spending and the revenue generated by vehicles.

I need to have an Accounts Receivables and a Received statement for each trip.

Is there a standard way to achieve this? I believe a similar approach is used in typical e-commerce systems. Any and every help is appreciated.

**Edit 1**

[image: Small Excel Approach]

I believe I can record all the transactions in this way. Since a trip already contains vehicles and customers, probably I can derive the respective transactions to them.

Comment: You may not get answer if you do not show your first attempt. Easiest for us to answer on an existing basis.

Comment: AFAIK, No.  There is not a "standard" way to do this.   Basically, you are asking us to find an existing Django model for you to reuse.  That is off-topic.

Comment: @TimothéDelion I have added the approach I'm taking. Still not at development but I would like to understand the best approach here.

Comment: @StephenC right! an existing Django model may help as well. However, I'm preferring to figure out a model that can serve the purpose.

I need to understand what each trip cost me and the income I generate (receivable and actual), how much revenue each vehicle generated (vehicles will have other expenses too, like insurance)

I hope I'm providing a clear picture.